# Memory address out of bounds when trying to print user input out in MIPS

Tags: mips, system-calls, memory-address, mips32

[Screenshot of my code and registers from SPIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT48t.jpg)

Trying to make a Hello World program that deals with input, but I'm running into a "Memory address out of bounds" error when trying to print out said input.

I've tried changing line 14 to `move $s0, $a0` and the program runs and exits successfully, except it's printing `prompt` in place of where I want user input... So I end up with "Hello... Nice to meet you, *What is your name?*\n!" instead of my desired outout: "Hello... Nice to meet you, \n!"

Comment: Try single step debugging.  Check each instruction to make sure it does what you want.

Comment: I did, but not sure what's going wrong :( The error is thrown around line 23.

Comment: Look at the value in `$a0` at that syscall.  What do you find in your data at that location?  Is it the address of a string or just junk?  What address would you want it to be?  Why do two syscall #4's in a row instead of one longer syscall #4?

Comment: Here's a question: When you get your input, e.g. "Jenny", is there a null terminator at the end of that? The null terminator is the only way that the syscall knows when a string ends. Without it, the syscall will read whatever data happens to be stored after your string, printing it as if it were ASCII text, and will keep doing this until it reaches a zero byte. Chances are the operating system/simulator has realized that you're reading memory that isn't supposed to be read as a string and has halted your program.